# Easiest way to write a Java SOAP client that consumes a non-wsdl PHP SOAP server?

Tags: java, soap-client

I've been successfully writing PHP non-wsdl SOAP servers and clients. However, I don't know how to consume one of my non-wsd SOAP servers by a Java SOAP client.

Could someone please provide me with a simple way to do this, preferably without external libraries.

Assuming http://example.com/SOAP/m1/server.php is the URL where the PHP SOAP server located.